# Problems with delete in destructor

Tags: c++

I wrote this code.
The constructor works normally, but in the destructor I get "Windows has triggered a breakpoint." How should I correct this?

```
template class CyclicalArray { 
private: 
   T* mem_ptr;
public: 
   CyclicalArray(size_t capacity, const T& default_value) {
   this->default_value = default_value; 
   this->capacity = capacity; 
   head_index = 0; 
   mem_ptr = ::new T[capacity]; //memory allocating 
   for(T* p = mem_ptr; p < mem_ptr + capacity * sizeof(T); p += sizeof(T)) { 
       ::new (p) T (default_value); //initialization 
   } 
} 
~CyclicalArray() { 
   for(T* p = mem_ptr + sizeof(T); p < mem_ptr + capacity * sizeof(T); p += sizeof(T)) { 
      p->~T();
   } 
   delete[] mem_ptr; 
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're going to perform placement new, you need to do it on raw memory.  Something like:

```
template class CyclicalArray { 
private: 
   T* mem_ptr;
public: 
   CyclicalArray(size_t capacity, const T& default_value) {
   this->default_value = default_value; 
   this->capacity = capacity; 
   head_index = 0; 
   mem_ptr = reinterpret_cast<T*>( ::new char[capacity * sizeof(T)]); //memory allocating 
   for(T* p = mem_ptr; p < mem_ptr + capacity; ++p) { 
       ::new (p) T (default_value); //initialization 
   } 
} 
~CyclicalArray() { 
   // this 
   for(T* p = mem_ptr + capacity; p != mem_ptr; --p) { 
      (p-1)->~T();
   } 
   delete[] reinterpret_cast<char*>( mem_ptr); 
}
```

Otherwise you'll call the T destructor twice on the same object memory (not a good thing to do).

Also, since your `p` pointers are of type `T*`, you can perform simple increment/decrements on it - the compiler will deal with the `sizeof(T)` issue as a normal course of pointer arithmetic.

Finally, strictly speaking you should destroy the array elements in descending order (the opposite of construction).

I hope this catches most or all the bugs.

You might really want to consider using something like std::vector as the store. An example using `std::vector<>` follows (with a few other syntax fixes). I'm not sure if your class would really need a copy of the `default_value` or the `head_index` - I left them in assuming that you plan to use them in other methods:

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class CyclicalArray { 
private: 
   std::vector<T> backing_store;
   T default_value;
   size_t head_index;

public: 
    CyclicalArray(size_t capacity, const T& def_val) : 
        backing_store(capacity, def_val), 
        default_value( def_val), 
        head_index(0) {
    } 

    ~CyclicalArray() {}
};
```

Note how much simpler the constructor and destructor are, since all the complexity of your first class is managed by `std:vector`.

Answer (score 7):

You're probably going way beyond the end of the `mem_ptr` array.  In C and C++, pointer arithmetic is in units of the type involved, not bytes.  For example, if you have `int *a;`, then if `a` is 0x100, and `sizeof(int) == 4`, `a + 1` is 0x104.

Therefore, you're incrementing `p` by the size of the type squared, since adding 1 to it will move it `sizeof(T)` bytes, and so adding `sizeof(T)` to it will increment it far too much.

Not to mention that you don't need to call individual destructors in an array, since `delete []` takes care of that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use global function `operator new` instead of operator `new`. It will allocate memory but will not call constructors. Same for delete:

```
template class CyclicalArray { 
private: 
   T* mem_ptr;
public: 
   CyclicalArray(size_t capacity, const T& default_value) {
   this->default_value = default_value; 
   this->capacity = capacity; 
   head_index = 0; 
   mem_ptr = static_cast<T*>(::operator new[] (sizeof(T)*capacity)); //memory allocating 
   for(T* p = mem_ptr; p < mem_ptr + capacity; p ++ ) { 
       ::new (p) T (default_value); //initialization 
   } 
} 
~CyclicalArray() { 
   for(T* p = mem_ptr; p < mem_ptr + capacity; p ++) { 
      p->~T();
   } 
   ::operator delete[]( static_cast<void*>(mem_ptr) ); 
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the ugliness can be hidden by using `std::allocator<T>` and `allocate(capacity)`, `construct(p, default_value)`, `destroy(p)` and `deallocate(mem_ptr, capacity)`?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling your constructors and destructors twice because you are using a new-expression and a delete-expression:

```
// This allocates and calls constructor
mem_ptr = ::new T[size];

// This calls the destructor and deallocates the memory
delete[] mem_ptr;
```

If you want to just allocate raw memory, you can explicitly call operator new:

```
// This simply allocates raw memory
mem_ptr = ::operator new(sizeof(T) * size);

// And this simply deallocates memory
::operator delete(mem_ptr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use placement new at all? That code basically boils down to this:

```
template <class T>
class CyclicalArray { 
private: 
    T* mem_ptr;
    size_t capacity;
    T default_value;
    size_t head_index;
public: 
    CyclicalArray(size_t capacity, const T& default_value) : capacity(capacity), default_value(default_value), head_index(0) {
       mem_ptr = new T[capacity](default_value); //memory allocating and construction
    }

    ~CyclicalArray() { 
        delete[] mem_ptr; 
    }
};
```

**EDIT:** If you do want to use placement new, your loop should look like this:

```
for(T* p = mem_ptr; p != mem_ptr + capacity; ++p) {
```

No need to scale things by `sizeof(T)`, that is done for you in C/C++.